# Design pattern for image binarization library

Tags: c++, design-patterns, image-processing

I am now developing an image binarization library, and in this library classical binarization methods such as Sauvola and Otsu method will be implemented. Now my question is how I can design the library elegantly. For the now being, I have two solutions:

Solution 1:

```
    class Binarization
    {
    public:
       BiinterfacePtr interface_;
       enum BinarizationMethods
       {
           Method1, Method2, Method3, Method4
       }
       void set(BinarizationMethods method, Image *p_in, Image *p_out, Binarizationpara &para)
       {
           if (method == Method1)
           {
               BiinterfacePtr interfacetemp(new BinarizationMethod1());
               interface_ = interfacetemp;
            }
           if (method == Method2)
           {
            BiinterfacePtr interfacetemp(new BinarizationMethod2());
               interface_ = interfacetemp;
           } 
           ....
       }
       bool run()
       {  
          interface_->run();
        }
       Image* output()
       {
          return interface->output();
        }
}
```

As you can see, the implementation of different binarization methods is done in the `Biinterface` class. When we use `Binarization` class, we can denote the method we want to employ by invoking the `set` method. However, ad different binarization methods may have different parameter setting, the structure of `Binarizationpara`will become complicated.

Solution 2

```
class BinarizationMethod1()
{
  public:
    perform_binarization(Image *p_in, Image *p_out, BinarizationMethod1Para &para);
}

class BinarizationMethod2()
{
  public:
    perform_binarization(Image *p_in, Image *p_out, BinarizationMethod2Para &para);
}
```

My question is which one is better. Ideas about designing the library will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for the Factory pattern (you have a rather rudimentary one implemented right now). How much variation will there be between your various constructor signatures?

Comment: @alrikai Thanks for the comments. The constructor signatures are quite different depending on the adopted binarization method. I think Shinosha has given a very good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a simple [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which kinda looks like your first solution, only I'd use constructor injection. I don't really see why use an enum, it's tightly coupled and not the best way to maintain your application. You might as well pass the method you want to your Binarization module directly. If you need to pass parameters to your methods just use their run method (of course if they all have the same one, otherwise you could use the methods constructors). Moreover this makes the creation and maintenance of new methods easy.

[image: Strategy pattern for Binarization]

For example, you can just do :

```
Binarization binarization(new SauvolaMethod()...);
binarization->run();
```

*Disclaimer : I'm not a C++ guy*

Comment: It's ok neither is anyone else

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I will update for those interested.
Answers to this question can easily be misguided.  If you are going to write a quality image binarization library, but haven't thought it through, here are some things you have to plan on before you even start.

1. There is no good image reader / writer baked natively into in C++ so you probably need to create a generic Image concept that will work with 3rd party libraries.  But will that image hold a 32b RGBA value or an 8b Gray Scale / Black and White value?  This can have a dramatic affect on design.
2. Once you can finally process an image, you'll find that your algorithms will run way too slowly without integral image optimization.  All local adaptive thresholding algorithms can share this.  Make sure it is part of your design.
3. Now that you are using integral images, the values needed to be stored in those structures can be too large for big images.  You now need to design in a "tiling" approach which will process large images in chunks.
4. Now that you are tiling, why do it sequentially?  This should cause you to question everything and wonder why you are not sending it to the GPU in the first place to be processed by a custom kernel.
5. You have finally made it to the end.  Your library looks great, has all the magic, but it probably isn't as fast as it could be because you didn't want to go the GPU route and instead opted for an OO inheritance heavy design.  Many compilers are not capable of optimizing such structures as well as you may have hoped.  You'll never really notice this until you compare it against a monolithic function that does the equivalent.

To this fifth point, if you need more speed, I have one recommendation: **Templates and the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.**

If you are sticking with the OOD approach, I would also use the **Strategy Pattern** as recommended above, but also leverage a **Facade** to provide a cleaner experience.

Good luck!  I speak from experience: https://github.com/brandonmpetty/Doxa